# Under what circumstances does PHP's openssl_random_pseudo_bytes return false?

Tags: php, php-openssl

[The PHP documentation for `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) says:

> #### Return Values
>
> Returns the generated string of bytes on success, or **false** on failure.

What would cause `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` to fail? Can this be manually triggered for testing purposes? I tried disabling the entire openssl PHP extension, but as expected that raised an error due to the function not being found.

Answer (score 0):

When PHP cannot quantify the integer in a manner that will encrypt the integer, it will, in fact, return false.   It goes without saying, it is ASSUMED `php` uses whole numbers for this function .. However it appears they left room for non-whole numbers (less than 1) and negative integers .. Just in case.

For example:

```
<?php

echo test_rando(80); // Passes

echo test_rando(80.1); // Passes

echo test_rando(.9);  //  Fails

echo test_rando(-1);  // Faile


function test_rando($rando_in){

    $rando = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($rando_in);

    if ($rando === false){
        return  "\n\n$rando_in | WAS FALSE\n\n ";
    }else{
        return "\n\n$$rando_in | $rando\n\n";
    }

}
```

Output:

```
80 | ghg'O8I*%&E(Et(wX"vUH$0
t|5|衖y䰆rW+;

80.1 |  &iGkb s`+[byaqvgөrTE݁ᨈ\Ukfb'

0.9 | WAS FALSE

-1 | WAS FALSE
```

Version of PHP

```
PHP 8.0.10 (cli) (built: Aug 26 2021 15:50:07) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.10, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.10, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

--

```
PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.16 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.16, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Because PHP was not able to quantify `.9` or `-1` (anything less than 1), even though IT IS an integer, it will fail.  Although this isn't expressly denoted in the documentation, one can assume this prevents fatal errors (division by zero and such) and presents error handling possibility for anyone who might be doing arithmetic on said integer before it's passed through the `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` function.

Comment: For `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(-42)` I get `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Length must be greater than 0`, so it crashes and still doesn't return `false`.

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.4.24 and I can't get any of your examples to return `false`. They either pass (return a string of the correct length) or crash.

Comment: Strange!  I am running it on 8.0.10 and it works .. I can also verify on another server (7.0) that it works as well.   I do not have access to 7.4

Comment: What are your error settings like? Mine are very strict (`E_ALL`).

Comment: Ever since PHP 7.4.0 (which includes [this commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/74c0e580efa8feb282d0da9c830c6bd01b08b45e)), `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` will not return `false` on failure, but will throw an exception. This should be the same regardless of the error reporting level, so for testing you can just provide a value less than 0 (for example) and assert that it fails as expected (return `false` before 7.4.0 and throw exception from 7.4.0).

Comment: @msbit Thanks for that! I can confirm that on PHP 7.3 a negative number does indeed return false, whereas on PHP 7.4 it throws an exception instead. Does this mean the PHP documentation needs to be updated to reflect this change?

Comment: I would say yes. Documentation is at https://github.com/php/doc-en/blob/master/reference/openssl/functions/openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.xml, be the change you wish to see in the world ✌️